# div element moves when i resize. issue about positioning

Tags: html, css

i am beginner and i have a little problem i couldn't be able to fix for last three hours. so i think it's safe to ask.

I placed a fixed menu and video header to my page successfully.

But when I wanted to place a text after video header, i had problem with that text when i resize. Here is the picture, see the blue text please;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ivwR.jpg

When i watch the page fullscreen, it is perfect.

but the more i resize, the more the blue text goes down and looks ugly.

Here you can see my css and html codes;

```
body {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.basicf {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  color: blue;
}

.basic {
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:0%;
    height: 70%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}

video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="header">menu here.</div>

<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div><!-- end video-container -->

<div class="basicf">please start just after video header.</div>

<div class="basic">Where is this text?</div>
```

In div element `basicf` i tried `top: 80%;` or `padding: 80% 0 0 0 0` it's only good when it's fullscreen. I also tried some `position: absolute, relative etc.` but I couldn't fix.

Comment: vertical-align: top?

Comment: Have you tried your web browser's inspector to find out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.basicf {
  color: blue;
}

.basic {
  color: red;
}

#video-container {
    margin-top:10%;
    height: 70%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}

video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">menu here.</div>

<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div><!-- end video-container -->

<div class="basicf">please start just after video header.</div>

<div class="basic">Where is this text?</div>
```

Comment: i deleted `height: 70%;` line from  `#video-container` part. the video is way to big than i wanted but it solved positioning problem of texts. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use position: absolute in your case.

Try this:

```
.basicf {
position: relative;
color: blue;
vertical-align: top;
}

#video-container {
position: relative;
top:10%;
left:0%;
height: 70%; 
width:100%;
overflow: hidden;
z-index:-1;
}
```

The reason your basic is not showing is because you do everything with absolute and your elements hide each other if they overlap.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted when you just had "don't use position absolute".

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage is breaking because you are using `position` wrong. Don't go and position everything absolute and fixed, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

When you don't use `position` anywhere, HTML will just render as you have written it, top to bottom. By positioning stuff, you kill that order and it will be positioned as you position it. So, since the text got `top:80%`, it will always get 80% on top. In other words: it is stuck on the page and will not move with if you resize horizontally, only vertically.

Here's your edited CSS:

```
body {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    margin: 0px;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.basicf {
    color: blue;
}
.basic {
    color: red;
}
#video-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 70%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And a **[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc0y8tme/1/)**.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have to say it's a progress but when I re-size, video gets smaller to fit and blue text staying it's same place. so result is still the same like in the picture I have added to my question post.

Comment: Did you even check the fiddle I linked to? ("working Fiddle")

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing your `absolute` positioning and use `relative` with a clear on the text to keep it below, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8usssfn9/).

```
.basicf {
position: relative;
color: blue;
    clear:both;
}

#video-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10%;
    left:0%;
    height: 70%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}
```